# get JSP list item from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, jstl

i have Servlet, JSP page and Javascript. so from servlet i pass list to jsp and it draws results. each result is presented in table and has delete button. so i want to get ID from the result i want to delete and alert value.

${delete} - is button. when there is no session button is hidden, because when session exists i pass `String delete = "<input id=\"${emp.id}\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"test()\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"btn\">";`

here is JSP Foreach:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.product}" var="emp">
                        <table border='1' align='center' cellpadding="5" width="60%" class="products" cellspacing="0" style=" text-align: left; font-size: 13px; color: honeydew;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 10px; text-align: right">${emp.addDate}</td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">${emp.manufacturer} ${emp.model} ${emp.screenSize}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="7"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${emp.category}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${emp.manufacturer}</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${emp.model}</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${emp.screenSize}</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>${emp.amountInStock}</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: right; font-size: 20px; font-style: italic;">${emp.price}</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 10px;">ID: ${emp.id} &nbsp; &nbsp;${emp.editDate}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        ${delete}
                        <hr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't build up HTML in Java. You're mixing responsibilities.

Replace `${delete}` with something like follows. Edit as necessary to do what you need.

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Delete ${emp.id}')">Delete</button>
```

Comment: this will work i know, but this button will appear even when session doesn't exist